# How to call a method in using attributes parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods, attributes

I have a static method by name `GetRole()` that return a string value. 
Now I want to call that in using attribute parameters.
for example:

```
[Authorize(Roles = GetRole())]
public ActionResult Get()
{
}

public static string GetRole()
{
   return "Admin";
}
```

But compiler get below error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Please help me to call a method in attributes.

Comment: You cannot. Only parameter values that can be resolved at compile-time are accepted.

Comment: Attributes are not stored as code, they are stored as metadata - that's why you can only use a limited range of constructs inside them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compiler error is pretty clear, you can't call any method when declaring an attribute (because its value must be known at compile-time) but you can derive **your own custom attribute**, derived from `AuthorizeAttribute` to perform all logic you need. Isn't what we all did to localize `NameAttribute` & friends before fancy long-waited localization-aware data annotations?

Proof of concept:

```
class DynamicAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {
    protected bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase context) {
        // Perform your logic here, eventually update Roles property
    }
}
```

And then:

```
[DynamicAuthorize]
public ActionResult Get() {
    // ...
}
```

This is just *one* possible way, there you can put your own logic or simply update `Roles` property and delegate to usual logic simply calling `base.AuthorizeCore(context)`. Be aware that all your code here must be thread-safe.

If you're working with static methods and you want to keep that logic inside your controller then you can play around to accept (for example) something like this:

```
[DynamicAuthorize(typeof(MyView), nameof(GetRole))]
```

Note that you can access controller and view names from `context.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData`.

Then invoke such static method. Note that if logic is really complex and greatly vary then you may want to centralize this logic and use other MVC *tools* to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.

This is a *fact*. There is no way around, an attribute argument must be compile time constant. You cannot call a method.

What you *can* do is define a constant:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public const string Role = "Admin";
    [Authorize(Roles = Role)]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
    }    
}
```

Constants are (as the name suggests) compile time constant, so you maybe this workaround helps you.

If you want to determine a value at *run-time*, this won't work as the attributes are assigned at *compile time*.

Comment: What was that downvote for? Probably because I don't know the `Authorize` attribute. But the question never stated that it is about a specific attribute with a specific implementation. Don't even know where `AuthorizeCore` (as mentioned by Adriano Repetti) gets called.

Answer (score 0):

i used my own method for Authorizing logged in user.

look at it, maybe it will help you.

```
 public static bool GetRole(string Codename)
    {            
        if (LogInUser == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

and to check whether user has access or not,

```
if (!Utility.GetRole("Admin"))
            return View("AccessDenied");
```

i also have code for standard built in authorization,

if you need it, just comment below.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

this method is better, because here you can pass list of Roles to be authorised, instead of single role.(Look at below, i passed admin and master both)

```
[Authorization(Roles = "admin,master")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
   //Your remaining code.
}
```

and to authorize it, i have these method.

```
public class Authorization : AuthorizeAttribute
{

public string Roles { get; set; }

protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    if (User != null)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Roles))
        {
            return true;
        }

        string[] split = Roles.Split(',');

        foreach (UserRole item in User)
        {
            if (split.Contains(item.Role.CodeName))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
    else
        return false;
}

protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
}
}
```

Comment: Hmmmmm, my downvote because it adds nothing to existing answers and nothing to existing AuthorizeAttribute (which already handles multiple roles...) while still not answering the question (invoking a method...). At least your other answer took an alternative approach (imperative instead of declarative authorization)

Comment: yes @AdrianoRepetti , maybe that's because we both are giving answer at some time..and i dont know you have given answer with same concept..